# A sequence $<a_n>$ does not converge to $L$.Prove that there exist a monotone subsequence of $<a_n>$ which also does not converge to $L$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $<a_n>$ does not converge to $L$.Then how can we prove that there exist a monotone subsequence of $<a_n>$ which also does not converge to $L$.

My try: Since $<a_n>$ does not converge to $L$,then there exist a subsequence which does not converge to $L$ and every sequence has a monotone subsequence .So the result follows.Thank you.plz check.

Comment: In "my try", (1) the first part is meaningless; if the sequence doesn't converge, you may as well take the whole thing as the subsequence, and (2) just because a sequence doesn't converge doesn't mean that a monotone subsequence also doesn't converge.

Comment: can you please give me some hint to prove this?

Comment: Unfortunately your argument is not sufficient.  The subsequence of $\langle a_n \rangle$ which does not converge to $L$ could just as well be the entire sequence.  Consider the case that every montone subsequence converges to $L$.

Comment: @hardmath: plz check:suppose every monotone subsequence converges which leads to $a_n $ converges ,so there exist some monotone subsequence which does not converges since $a_n$ does not converges.

Comment: Prove that for all monotone subsequence of $<a_n>$ which also are converge to $L$, then $<a_n>$ converges to $L$.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed use the lemma : every sequence of real numbers has a monotonic subsequence.

Since $(a_n)$ does not converge to $L$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\ge N;\left|a_n-L\right|\ge\epsilon$.

This implies the existence of some subsequence $(a_{\phi(n)})$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\left|a_{\phi(n)}-L\right|\ge\epsilon$.

Now take a monotonic subsequence of $(a_{\phi(n)})$

Comment: but @Adren what is stopping the monotonic subsequence of $(a_\phi(n))$ from converging to $L$  I feel we haven't shown that, or if we have I'm not seeing it?